# How to make Group height same as textbox height in fabric JS while scaling

Tags: fabricjs

I have more than one textbox. When I group all textboxes and scale the group horizontally height of group is not increase dynamically and content of textbox get vanish unlike independent textbox which increase height till the content end.

Below code I tried to set same height of group as of textbox but not working. Any Suggestion ?

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text1 = new fabric.Textbox('Text', {
  left: 10,
  top: 20,
  fontSize : 18,
  width: 300
})
canvas.add(text1);
var text2 = new fabric.Textbox('If this textbox grouped with above textbox, height will not increase on scaling horizontally and content get vanished but if scalling independently height increase', {
  left: 20,
  top: 40,
  fontSize : 18,
  width: 300
})

canvas.add(text2);

canvas.on('object:scaling', function(e) {
 /* if(e.target.type == "group"){
 var obj=e.target;
 
 obj.height=obj.item(0).height;
 obj.width=obj.item(0).width;
 
 
 }*/ 
    });
```

```css
canvas{
 border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.9/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```